# Google Classroom Python make return course materials aswell

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-classroom

Ok so basically, I'm trying to get all the course work there are for a course. But i only get in response the coursework that are not of type 'MATERIAL'. How can I do so that I get the coursework type 'MATERIAL' aswell?

Here is my python code:

````
resultcourses = service.courses().list().execute()
courses = resultcourses.get('courses', [])

for course in courses:
    resultscourseworks = service.courses().courseWork().list(courseWorkStates='PUBLISHED', 
    courseId=course['id']).execute()
    courseworks = courseworks + resultscourseworks.get('courseWork', [])```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to get the `Material` coursework as mentioned on the first paragraph of the [Manage Classwork](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-classwork) guide:

> Classroom has five types of Classwork: Assignments, Quiz Assignments,
> Questions (short answer and multiple choice), Materials, and Topics.
> **The Classroom API currently allows developers to read and write two of
> these types: Assignments and Questions.**

Comment: Oh ok, Thank you for your reply. Do you know a work around to this? Or when will they add this feature?

Comment: You can create an assignment with the material you want and then when retrieving the assignment you will get the material.

Also, you can create a feature request on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191645)